# play next for video array adds increment for index on click

Tags: jquery, arrays, html, video

I'm not sure if that really makes sense...

sorry, but I have no idea how to word that. The problem is with a play array function I have. The function is

```
$("#myVid").bind("ended", function() {
            $("#MyT").fadeIn(250);
            function playArray(ele, array) {
                index++;
                if (index >= array.length) {
                    index = i;
                }
                ele.src = array[index];
                ele.load();
                ele.play();
            }
            playArray(document.getElementById("myVid"), videos);
```

Basically, it plays the next video in the array when the one that was playing ends. The idea is that you can play any video in the array with the application of the `<li>` tag. Works fine.

Unless it's the second time you've clicked. At this point, the clicks "stack" so instead of playing the next video, it plays the one after the next video. How can I fix this?Edit: okay, here's the js

```
$(window).load(function(){
        var index = 0;
        var videos = ['images/Answer1b.m4v', 'images/Answer2b.m4v', 'images/Answer3b.m4v', 'images/Answer4b.m4v', 'images/Answer5b.m4v', 'images/Answer6b.m4v'];
        $("#MyT").fadeOut();
$("li, .thumbs").bind("touchstart click", function() {
        $("#bigPic").removeClass("move");
        $("#MyT").fadeIn(0);
        });

$('li', '.thumbs').on('touchend click', function() {
    index = $(this).index();
    var myVideo = document.getElementById('myVid');
        myVideo.src = videos[index];
        myVideo.load();
        myVideo.play();


        $("#myVid").bind("loadeddata", function() {
        $("#bigPic").addClass("move");
        $("#MyT").fadeOut(750);
        });

    $("#myVid").bind("playing", function() {
        ("#bigPic").removeClass("move");
        $("#MyT").fadeOut(750);
        });

        $("#myVid").bind("ended", function() {
            $("#bigPic").removeClass("move");
            $("#MyT").fadeIn(250);
            function playArray(ele, array) {
                index++;
                if (index   >= array.length) {
                    index = 1;
                }
                ele.src = array[index];
                ele.load();
                ele.play();
            }
            playArray(document.getElementById("myVid"), videos);
        });
    });
    video.on("timeupdate", function() {
        var currentPos = myVid.currentTime;
        var maxduration = myVid.duration;
        var perc = 100 * currentPos / maxduration;
        $(".timeBar").css("width",perc+"%");    
    });
    var updatebar = function(x) {
        var progress = $(".progress");
        var maxduration = myVid.duration;
        var percentage = 100 * position / progress.width();
        if(percentage > 100) {
            percentage = 100;}
        if(percentage < 0) {
            percentage = 0;}
        $(".timeBar").css("width",percentage+"%");  
        myVid.currentTime = maxduration * percentage / 100;
    };
});
```

I have things bound in two clicks (`touchstart` and `touchend`) because they were interfering if not set up like that...

Comment: When there is a click, decrease the index value by 1.

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon how would I go about this? (sorry, arrays are not my forte)

Comment: I cant come up with much, i can only speculate, at the line with index = $(this).index(); you grab the index of the video, then a few lines later in the playArray function you have index++; this may be causing a double increment which would cause a skip in the vids

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon I have tried that before, to no avail. Thank you very much for looking either way ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by using two different play functions.

one gets called when you click

```
$('li', '.thumbs').bind('touchend click', function() {
        $("#myVid").bind("loadeddata", function() {
        $("#bigPic").addClass("move");
        $("#MyT").fadeOut(750);
                });
        playVideo2( $(this).index() );
        });
```

and the other when the video ends

```
$("#myVid").bind("ended", function() {
    //stuff happens
 playVideo( (currentVideo + 1) % videos.length );
        });
```

with the two functions being the same except for the index

```
function playVideo(videoNumToPlay) {
            var myVideo = document.getElementById('myVid');
             myVideo.src = videos[videoNumToPlay];
             myVideo.load();
             myVideo.play();
             currentVideo = videoNumToPlay;
        }

        function playVideo2(index) {
            var myVideo = document.getElementById('myVid');
             myVideo.src = videos[index];
             myVideo.load();
             myVideo.play();
             currentVideo = index;
        }
```

oh, and the array is set up under `document.ready` instead of under the click, like so

```
var videos = ['images/intro01.m4v', 'images/intro02.m4v', 'images/intro3.m4v', 'images/talking1.m4v', 'images/chord.m4v', 'images/dizzy.mp4'],
        currentVideo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my initial comment:

When there is a click, decrease the index value by 1

Try adding this within your jquery $(document).ready function:

```
/*Target you play button click function here*/
$("#play-button").click(function(){
    index--;
});
```

Comment: oh, I did try that, but I can't use it because if I let the video play through(and it's only one click), it plays again before going to the second... Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Hey, I'm kind blank here now, can you add in some more snippets of code, ones that may be relevant? or just add all the JS involved with playing the video

Comment: okay, I've added the js, and if you have time to take a look, that would be much appreciated!